# How can I force Google Chrome to remember HTTPS credentials?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, https

Google Chrome is a great browser for sure, though I still see bugs there. Some of them are really annoying: my Chrome (at my work computer) does not offer to remember HTTPS authentication data, and I have to enter it manually each time I go to the secured resource for the first time after Chrome start - it simply does not offer to remember it. Sorry, I can't remember my credentials, don't ask why. :D But! The Chrome at my home computer successfully remembers these credentials after offering to remember them. I checked Chrome preferences (the according option is always set on [though it always offers to store form authentication data at simple "HTTP sites"]), I tried to clear even all passwords - Chrome still asks me to enter both username and password for that HTTPS site after I restart the browser... I don't know what I have do... Can I really force it to remember HTTPS credentials?

Thanks in advance.

UPD: My Chrome version is 6.0.472.63

Comment: Which installation is 6, the one at home or the one at work?

Comment: @Synetech inc. - the one at home. But I guess that it is not reproducable anymore. Can't tell from which version.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/913469/force-chrome-to-try-https-instead-of-http-when-possible/913513#913513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both Chrome installs are the same version, and yet are behaving differently, then there must me something messing it up at profile level.

I suggest creating a new profile from scratch, of copying your profile from the installation that does remember https credentials to the one that does not.

Creating a new profile is as easy as deleting (or renaming the folder) that contains the current one.

For guidelines on where Chrome stores its profiles, check http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

PD: profile = user data directory

Answer (score 10):

Here's how. (At least it worked on a HTTPS site I tried just then - ifttt.com) - it is indeed the autocomplete=on thing, but iirc I tried that extension but it didn't change anything. Instead, use this lighter solution.

Just save a bookmarklet, with this javascript code as the url data:

```
javascript:(function(){var ca,cea,cs,df,dfe,i,j,x,y;function n(i,what){return i+" "+what+((i==1)?"":"s")}ca=cea=cs=0;df=document.forms;for(i=0;i<df.length;++i){x=df[i];dfe=x.elements;if(x.onsubmit){x.onsubmit="";++cs;}if(x.attributes["autocomplete"]){x.attributes["autocomplete"].value="on";++ca;}for(j=0;j<dfe.length;++j){y=dfe[j];if(y.attributes["autocomplete"]){y.attributes["autocomplete"].value="on";++cea;}}}alert("Removed autocomplete=off from "+n(ca,"form")+" and from "+n(cea,"form element")+", and removed onsubmit from "+n(cs,"form")+". After you type your password and submit the form, the browser will offer to remember your password.")})();
```

Then go to the login page, click on the bookmarklet and click ok, log in, then after a few seconds the save password box will pop up. Hope that helps somebody or OP.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I was really annoyed that Safari on iOS can store my OWA password but not Chrome.

Comment: This is such valuable information, but unfortunately it does not answer the question, which is to save HTTP Auth data, not HTML form data to which autocomplete applies. I am upvoting it anyway, but I feel... dirty

Comment: It doesn't work for me (((

Comment: Doesn't work (anymore). But in my case it may be related to the "untrusted" self-signed server certificate (cert lifetime 10y)

Answer (score 4):

Some sites also send an attribute along with the form that prevents your browser from remembering user inputs.

The Chrome extension [autocomplete = on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/gdhbgagnmhdafendedikgjimegoipbnk) will override that and let you remember passwords for any site.

Comment: Thanks, but autocomplete on has nothing about restricted HTTPS access. Such authorization is not performed through forms.

Comment: It doesn't work